# Converting windows timezone to equivalent for PHP settings

Tags: php, windows, datetime, timezone, command-line-arguments

I am developing an application consisting of a web server using PHP and MySQL running on Windows that the user accesses through a web browser set to `http://localhost`. But I want it to work in all United States time zones, including most of the State of Arizona that does not observe daylight saving time. To configure this script, I need to make PHP use the same time zone as Windows.

I have a PHP script that gets the timezone from command line on Windows.  The results then need to be converted to the equivalent timezone in [PHP's list](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php).

Unfortunately I do not see a straightforward way to do this.  Here is the script:

```
       $comp_timezone = exec('systeminfo | findstr  /C:"Time Zone"');

       // results are: "Time Zone: (UTC-07:00) Arizona"

       date_default_timezone_set($comp_timezone);
```

What I need to do is convert the string result from `$comp_timezone` into something that the function `date_default_timezone_set` can use, but as the above example demonstrates, Arizona does not exist as a timezone for php, the closest one would be `America/Phoenix`.

So how do I convert a `systeminfo` timezone to a PHP one?

Comment: Which versions of `PHP`are you using ?

Comment: I don't thin there's a straight forward way to do it.
You will need a table for conversions, because even taking the (UTC-07:00) part, you will need to deal with the DST.
And even more trouble: Timezone depends of the date for the same place, event without DST like in the case of Chile: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Chile

Comment: America/Arizona  doesn't exist as a valid timezone in PHP.

Answer (score 5):

A few things:

1. The `systeminfo` command is just showing you the *display name* of the Windows time zone.  You will need the *identifier*.  You can use `tzutil.exe /g` to return this - though that's still not going to help you here.
2. PHP uses IANA time zones, not Windows time zones.  See [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for more information about the two different types of time zones.
3. The translation between the two is handled by [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) in [this file](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml).
4. For PHP, you can access CLDR data via the [Internationalization Package](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php).  Enable this by adding (or uncommenting) to your `php.ini` file:

   ```
   extension=php_intl.dll
   ```
5. Then you can simply call the following function to return the local time zone as an IANA identifier.  (Internally, it relies on [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) and CLDR to translate.)

   ```
   IntlTimeZone::createDefault()->getID()
   ```

   This will return `"America/Phoenix"` in your example.  You can then use it with any of PHP's normal time zone functions, including `date_default_timezone_set` if you wish.
6. Even though you *can* do this, think carefully about whether or not you really *should* do this.  In most cases, relying on the system's local time zone setting from a web application (or any server-side application) is an anti-pattern.  It's far too easy for the time zone to change.  It's a global setting which doesn't usually require any administrator rights.  It's also problematic if your data is not UTC based and you then try to migrate it from one server to another.  In the vast majority of cases, it's better to think about time zone at the application logic level, not system-wide or application-wide, and the time zone of the server hosting your code should usually be considered *irrelevant*.

Comment: Thanks!  I think this may be the solution I need!

Comment: I'm having a problem with the IntlTimeZone class.  It is giving an error that the class cannot be found.  However, viewing the manual with the 'basic examples', I was able to get them working.  I changed php.ini and enabled the extension and restarted apache, it seems related to just this class.  I tried both echo IntlTimeZone::createDefault()->getID(); and echo IntlTimeZone::getID();    Do you have any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: The `php_intl.dll` extension is not loaded by default.  You need to make sure its enabled in the `php.ini` file.  It's usually commented out.  You may need to restart your environment after making the change.

Comment: Yes, I enabled it in php.ini and restarted.  The basic example in the manual for that extension worked.  Unfortunately the IntlTimeZone class is not and there are no examples in the manual for it.

Comment: Perhaps you need to update?  I tried on 5.6.21 and it worked fine.

Comment: Counterpoint 6: The timestamps in application logfiles should be in the same timezone as other logfiles on the server so they can be easily searched to reconstruct a series of events.

Comment: @Magicianeer - sure, but really time in log files should always reflect UTC.  Otherwise you can have difficulties with ambiguities near daylight saving time transitions, and you will certainly have problems trying to correlate with servers running in other time zones.

Answer (score 0):

## READ MATT SOLUTION :)

---

My solution is to loop `DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers()` and try to find a match, i.e:.

```
$comp_timezone = exec('systeminfo | findstr  /C:"Time Zone"');
//Time Zone: (UTC +01:00) Lisbon
//we match the last word of $comp_timezone
preg_match_all('/(\w+)$/', $comp_timezone, $rawTz, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$rawTz = $rawTz[1][0]; //Lisbon

foreach (DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() as $timezone) {
            if(preg_match("/.*?\/$rawTz/", $timezone)){
                echo $timezone;
                //Europe/Lisbon
            }
        }
```

---

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/vnAN5p)

---

Notes:

1. `America/Arizona` doesn't exist as a valid `DateTimeZone` in `PHP`.
2. `DateTimeZone` is only available on `PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PHP 7`

Comment: Your P.S., is the thing I'm truly at a loss at how to solve.  The computer is saying Arizona but also gives the UTC, do you know how I can match that with the closest timezone that PHP allows?

Comment: I honestly don't know, because if you rely on `UTC-07:00` it may be different based on day light savings. What are you trying to achive ? if you don't set `date_default_timezone_set` php will use the `php.ini` value `date.timezone`

Comment: I am working on an oddly programmed 'desktop' application, which is actually written in PHP / mysql, but sits on windows computers.  The user then loads up the program with a web browser defaulting to localhost.    The problem I'm trying to fix is actually a daylight savings bug.  Arizona doesn't use daylight savings and the PHP program was off by an hour to the computer system's because of the php.ini setting.   Since this program goes to people all over the U.S., I'm trying to automate this so the program timezone matches the computer's with the date_default_timezone_set function.